# Empty S3 bucket | Access point ARN region is empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am trying to list the contents of my S3 bucket. I went through all the configuration steps and created & authenticated a user (I'm using Amplify). For record
`Auth.currentCredentials();` gives

```
Object {
  "accessKeyId": "ASIA6NIS4CMFGX3FWTNF",
  "authenticated": true,
  "expiration": 2020-10-14T13:30:49.000Z,
  "identityId": "eu-west-2:6890ebd2-e3f3-4e1d-9725-9f9218241f60",
  "secretAccessKey": "CGZsahSl53ulG9BJqGueM78xlMGhKcOs33UP2GUC",
  "sessionToken": "IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEIX//////////wEaCWV1LXdlc3QtM ...
}
```

My code:

```
async function listObjects() {
  Storage.list('s3://amplify-mythirdapp-dev-170201-deployment/',
    {
      level:'public',
      region:'eu-west-2',
      bucket:'arn:aws:s3:::amplify-mythirdapp-dev-170201-deployment'
    })
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Which throws an error: `Access point ARN region is empty`

If I instead do `bucket:amplify-mythirdapp-dev-170201-deployment` it just returns `Array []`

But `aws s3api list-objects --bucket amplify-mythirdapp-dev-170201-deployment` correctly lists objects

What am I missing?

FYI I've also asked this question at [aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2828](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2828).

Comment: I believe that the first parameter to Storage.list is the S3 key prefix you're interested in, like `'photos/'`. For bucket, I believe that you should specify the bucket name, not ARN.

Comment: it doesn't have a prefix, it's just in `/`. If I specify the bucket name as I said above it returns `Array []`

Comment: And if you specify no prefix using empty string like `Storage.list('', { ... })`?

Comment: same result. I tried `/` , `*`, `/*` as well